# How to interpret modified Diebold and Mariano test?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, diebold-mariano-test

I would appreciate if you could let me know to conclude about the modified Diebold and Mariano test when our alternative hypothesis is less? How about greater?

```
library(forecast)
forecast <- ts(c( 96, 99,102, 96,105, 99, 99,103, 98,106))
observed <- ts(c( 96,101,107,108, 93,103, 99,105,103, 98))
forecast2 <- ts(c(105, 94,107,101,111,115,104,111,111,116))
print(dm.test((forecast-observed), (forecast2-observed),alternative = "two.sided"))  
print(dm.test((forecast-observed), (forecast2-observed),alternative = "less"))  
print(dm.test((forecast-observed), (forecast2-observed),alternative = "greater"))
```

Comment: Do you have any trouble interpreting the unmodified DM test? The interpretation of the modified test is the same. Modification simply allows for nonzero autocorrelation in forecast errors.

Comment: @RichardHardy. Yes, could you please explain it?

Comment: Have you read a textbook entry on the Diebold-Mariano test? What exactly did you find confusing? It is just a $t$-test that can be interpreted in a pretty regular way. Also, I can warmly recommend [Diebold's (2015) paper](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/papers/paper113/Diebold_DM%20Test.pdf) on the use and abuse of the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you happen to reject the null hypothesis of equal expected predictive loss, $H_0\colon E(L(e_1))=E(L(e_2))$, then

- under $H_{1a}\colon E(L(e_1))\neq E(L(e_2))$, you favor the view that the expected losses are unequal (`alternative="two.sided"`);
- under $H_{1b}\colon E(L(e_1))> E(L(e_2))$, you favor the view that the expected loss from the first forecast is larger (`alternative="less"`);
- under $H_{1c}\colon E(L(e_1))< E(L(e_2))$, you favor the view that the expected loss from the second forecast is larger (`alternative="greater"`).

You can find the same interpretation phrased another way in the functions' [help file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.20/topics/dm.test).